# How do i make date format uniform for all formats after reading from Database?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In this piece of code I am reading the date from SQL database. The code is working fine in local workspace as it is converting to yyyy/MM/dd format. However on production server it seems the date is in format of MM/dd/yyyy format and hence it is not binding the dates to UI. I don't know how to make it uniform across any formats.

```
ValidFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ValidFrom"]),
ValidTill = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ValidTill"]),
ValidFromString = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ValidFrom"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
ValidTillString = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ValidTill"]).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
```

View.cshtml:

```
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<Module.Models.Somemodel>
    @using PagedList.Mvc;

     <td><input style="max-width:140px;" type="date" id="validFrom-@item.RowId" value=@item.ValidFromString /></td>
  <td><input style="max-width:140px;" type="date" id="validTill-@item.RowId" value=@item.ValidTillString /></td>
```

How do I tackle this issue to make sure no matter what system format, the date binds to the UI?

Comment: **WHAT** SQL database? SQL is just the query language - used by almost every relational database system. Please add a **concrete** RDBMS tag - `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server` or whatever else you might be using!

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Then ***please*** add a `sql-server` tag to your question!

Comment: Someone woke up on the wrong side of the bed today. That was unnecessarily hostile, and also not necessarily relevant to be that upset about.

Comment: @chaturvedi_anshumaan if you are able to, perhaps you can just have the date be returned as a string from the db. Format it either at the db or at the backend and return as a string to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`DisplayFormatAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netframework-4.8) on your model properties. You may need to add an appropriate `using` statement to pull in the `DataAnnotations` namespace.

```cs
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public DateTime ValiDtill { get; set; }
```